# Using Uri for .wav files

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, uri

I need to play some .wav files in a `wpf` project. No prior experience with `Uri` so I am stuck. I have placed the two `.wav` in my Rescources file and I am declaring:

```
Uri uri2 = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/WindowsExclamation.wav", UriKind.Absolute);

Uri uri1 = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/WindowsCriticalStop.wav", UriKind.Absolute);
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
```

I have put a break point on the following point:

```
player.Open(uri2);
player.Play();
```

When running the code I get this exception for uri2 Authority:

```
{"The generic authority 'application:,,,' is not a valid dns name."}
```

Comment: Take a look at MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using simpler relative `Uri` :

```
Uri uri2 = new Uri(@"../../Resources/WindowsExclamation.wav", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: I have tried and I get: {"This operation is not supported for a relative URI."}

Comment: updated my answer slightly, the path should be relative to executable file location (I assume it is `bin\debug` folder). Can't get it work with pack uri, but relative uri does work for me (.NET 4.5, VS2012).

Comment: it workded with Uri("WindowsExclamation.wav", UriKind.Relative)

Answer (score 1):

When referencing project resources from XAML in WPF, I find that it is generally easiest to us this format to locate the relevant files:

```
"/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.type"
```

This can also be referenced and used with a `Uri` object:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.type", 
    UriKind.Relative);
```

You could also expose this value as a `string` property and then simply data bind it to the `MediaElement.Source` property:

You can find out more information from the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) page on MSDN.